# Cell-based NSTableView with custom Cell binding

Tags: swift, nstableview, nstextfieldcell

A **cell-based**  NSTableView has `Name` column with a `NameCell` derived from NSTextFieldCell in which, besides the text it draws a custom pie progress indicator (in the very same cell, not in a separate column).

It mimics the one in Finder's Name column, when a big file is downloaded.

I've bound the column's value to the  `filesAC` array controller in order to show the text field,

```
 columnName.bind(.value, to: filesAC as Any, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects.fileName", options: nil)
```

But how to bind the `pieProgress` of the `NameCell` to the `progress` (of the `File` object in the array) ?

Comment: Why do you use a pattern (cell-based) which is outdated for almost 10 years?

Comment: I made already a working view-based version but... Potentially over 1M rows. Outdated, not deprecated.

Comment: See NSTableView.h "Note: cell-based NSTableViews are deprecated in Mac OS 10.10.  Prefer the view-based interface.". Is the user going to read 1M rows? Is the cell editable?

Comment: Cell-based table API is deprecated except `tableView(_ : dataCellFor: row: )`  and `tableView(_ : willDisplayCell: for: row: )`.  I think it means that cell-based tables are not entirely deprecated but only the usage of custom subclasses of NSCell is. In other words, one can safely use cell-based table only with "standard" cells.

Answer (score 0):

A cell-based solution would imply overriding `dataCell(forRow:)` from NSTableColumn in order to return the custom subclassed cell `NameCell` and set the binding for the `NameCell.progress`, as per row.  But `dataCell(forRow:)` is deprecated.

A view-based solution is, inside FilesTable class:

```
self.bind(.content, to: filesAC as Any, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects", options: nil)
...
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
 ...
  cell = NameCellView(frame:frame)
  cell.bind(NSBindingName(rawValue: #keyPath(NameCellView.progress)), to: cell, withKeyPath: "objectValue.progress", options: nil)
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to bind the column to the objects in the array controller, not the `fileName` property. That is, use `"arrangedObjects"` as the key path, not `"arrangedObjects.fileName"`.

Then, your custom cell class will override the setter for `objectValue`. It would pass the `fileName` property of the new object on to the superclass but would also retain the object as its own value. You would have to override the getter, too, to return that object.

When you need the value for the progress indicator, you would consult the `progress` property of the current value object.

All of that said, use a view-based table view. :)

Comment: Would the cell react to `progress` changes or only to full `objectValue` change?   Anyway, if I get it right, overriding `objectValue` means subclassing NSCell and then use of `dataCell` which is deprecated. End of game.

Comment: I thought you're already using a subclass of `NSTextFieldCell` named `NameCell`. But, you're correct about the KVO not firing. Good point. So, I recommend you add a synthetic property to your model object. Its value can just be `self`, but it can be set up to trigger change notifications when either `progress` or `fileName` change. That way, `objectValue` will be set again and the cell will be asked to redraw.

Comment: Yes,  subclass of `NSTextFieldCel` indeed. Usage of `dataCell` remains unavoidable, does it?

Comment: I guess I'm confused by your original question, then. It implies that you already have a cell-based table view set up that's using your `NameCell` class as the cell class. I figured you'd already gotten over that hurdle. Anyway, you can still set up a cell-based table view in IB and change the class of the column cell.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and patience.